# add border to jquery datatable excluding the search bar

Tags: jquery, css, border, datatables

this might be an easy question, but i need your help.
How to add border to jquery datatable excluding the search bar?
I tried using css but the border include the search bar.

```
    .table1{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: #A1A1A1;
}

$.fn.dataTableExt.oJUIClasses.sWrapper = "table1";
```

I prepared a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/X65td/

Answer (score 0):

If you are having search bar as table's first row you can use following script to add style to your table:

```
$(function() {
    $("#table-id").find("tr:not(:first)").addClass("table-class");
});
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesnt work. i am using jquery datatable rather than the regular table.

Comment: can you prepare a fiddle to test?

Answer (score 0):

I have using below code in my case and it works fine for me, i am using chrome:

`#dataTableId
{
    border: 1px solid black !important;
}`